# Как присвоить переменные селектам?

Tags: jquery

```
var sub = $('.sub_city select');

sub.on('click', function...

$('.sub_city select option')...

$('.sub_city select option:selected').each(function(){...
```

Как в 3-м и 4-м случае использовать переменную sub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3-й - sub.find("option").on...; 4-й - sub.find("option:selected").on...